# storing output of perl command into a variable

Tags: perl, variables

This works fine
`system("perl -c C:/Users/mytest/scripts/file_name.pm")`
This command gives many lines of output in cygwin and a single syntak ok line in centos. since ill be using cygwin, what am trying to do is to get this output into a variable and use it later in my program. How can i do it?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `system`, use backticks:

```
my $output = `perl -c C:/Users/mytest/scripts/file_name.pm`;
```

if you want to also include STDERR output, use:

```
my $output = `perl -c C:/Users/mytest/scripts/file_name.pm 2>&1`;
```

Comment: yep i tried this even with backticks.. but its not working. its directly printing the output to the terminal

Comment: possibly your script is outputting things to another stream, like STDERR; see my edit...

Comment: `use strict; 
use warnings;  chdir('C:/Users/WARTS/apple/auto/lib/perl');  system("perl -c C:/Users/mytest/scripts/file_name.pm");`  you were ryt.. since am new to perl scripting can u organize d edit n tell me how it works? Thanks